# why are stdout_lines [1,2] and [3,4] strings instead of arrays?

Tags: ansible

A [shell command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) outputs one array per line on the standard output: `[1,2]` then `[3,4]`. I would like to use each element of the array as a parameter to a module and decided to [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over [stdout_lines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#return-values). However, `item.0` and `item.1` contains the first and second character of the string instead of the first and second element of the array.

- Why is `item` a string instead of an array?
- What would be the most elegant way to get what I need?

Here is a reproducer to help understand the question, using ansible 2.7.5. The following play:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: one array per line
      shell: |
        echo '[1,2]'
        echo '[3,4]'
      register: result

    - name: each item is an array
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: accessing the first element of an item
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} => {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

The actual output is:

```sh
TASK [each item is an array] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 2]) => {
    "msg": [
        1, 
        2
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 4]) => {
    "msg": [
        3, 
        4
    ]
}

TASK [accessing the first element of an item] ************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 2]) => {
    "msg": "[ => 1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 4]) => {
    "msg": "[ => 3"
}
```

but I was expecting:

```sh
TASK [each item is an array] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 2]) => {
    "msg": [
        1, 
        2
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 4]) => {
    "msg": [
        3, 
        4
    ]
}

TASK [accessing the first element of an item] ************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 2]) => {
    "msg": "1 => 2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 4]) => {
    "msg": "3 => 4"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with Pilou on #ansible-fr@irc.freenode.net, a simple solution was found.

It is enough to trigger a [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) evaluation by assigning another variable with the content of `item`. It will be converted from string to a structure, if possible. See the test playbook updated with the solution below.

```
      debug:
        msg: "{{ array.0 }} => {{ array.1 }}"
      vars:
        array: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

There is no rationale explaining why `stdout` is converted into a structure when possible but not the elements in `stdout_lines`. It is how the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module is implemented. It is possible that it will change in the future. If that's the case, the proposed solution will keep working. Only it would not be necessary.

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: one array per line
      shell: |
        echo '[1,2]'
        echo '[3,4]'
      register: result

    - name: each item is an array
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: accessing the first element of an item
      debug:
        msg: "{{ array.0 }} => {{ array.1 }}"
      vars:
        array: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to convert the list of strings to the list of lists.

```
    - name: convert strings to lists
      set_fact:
        lists: "{{ lists }} + [ {{ item }} ]"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: accessing the 1st and 2nd element of a list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} => {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ lists }}"
```

Comment: this is interesting, thanks :-) I'm still looking for a more elegant solution but what you propose works indeed.